# Why is sizeof(my struct) smaller than I expected it to be?

Tags: c++, sizeof, memory-alignment

```
#include <iostream>
typedef struct Node

{

    int key;
    int ltag, rtag;
    struct Node* lchild, * rchild;

}Node;
Node* getNewNode(int key)
{
    Node *p =(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
     
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

When defining a binary tree, I found a problem. For example, in this code, the int variable takes up 4 bytes, and there are 3 int variables. Plus the  `Node* lchild` and `Node* rchild`, shouldn't it be 36 bytes?

My own idea is that `lchild` is regarded as the same node structure, so there are also 12 bytes in lchild, that is, three int variables. But the compiler told me that it only has 20 bytes:

[image: A screenshot of a line of code reading Node *p = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)); There is an IDE tooltip displayed below it showing the value of sizeof(Node) to be (size_t)20U]

Why is this so? It should also be 36 bytes if aligned naturally.

Comment: `sizeof(Node) /*20 in your case*/ = 3 * sizeof (int) /*4 in your case*/+ 2 * sizeof (Node*) /*4 in your case*/ /*+ padding, 0 in your case*/`

Comment: "the int variable takes up 4 bytes, while the int variable has 3"  Huh...?

Comment: Please don't include unrelated tags and don't post images of code. Thank you.

Comment: Pointers are usually 4 bytes size.

Comment: `sizeof(Node*)` is unrelated to `sizeof(Node)`.

Comment: lchild and rchild are _pointers_ - thus also occupying 4 bytes (on most systems) - therefore your compiler is right, 3x 4 bytes (int) + 2x 4 bytes(ptr)= 20 bytes for the structure (not regarding any padding)

Comment: @Lundin
 Sorry, I want to say that there are three int variables, each of which occupies four bytes, so the size should be 12 bytes

Comment: If `Node` included two copies of itself then it's size would be **infinite** not 36 bytes. But it doesn't include copies of itself, only *pointers* to itself.

Comment: That's what the `*` means in your struct declaration. Try removing those and see what happens.

Comment: You code is a very weird mix of C and C++. In C you can't use `<iostream>` and you wouldn't cast the result of `malloc` explicitly. In C++ you wouldn't use the `typedef struct Node { /*...*/ } Node;` syntax but simply `struct Node { /*...*/ };` instead. Also, wouldn't put `struct` before `Node` when declaring the members. Also, you wouldn't use `malloc` to create new `Node` objects. You would use `new` instead, or even better, use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers. Technically it is still valid C++ in this specific case, but especially the `malloc` will be wrong for non-trivial types.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the code and examining the `sizeof()` the member types of `Node`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    int key;
    int ltag, rtag;
    Node* lchild, * rchild;
};

int main()
{
    // size of individual types making up the struct:
    std::cout << "sizeof(int) = " << sizeof(int) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(Node*) = " << sizeof(Node*) << std::endl;
    // we might expect sizeof(Node) to equal whatever this line prints out:
    std::cout << "sizeof(int) * 3 + sizeof(Node*) * 2 = "
              << sizeof(int) * 3 + sizeof(Node*) * 2 << std::endl;
    // but only this line will tell us for sure
    std::cout << "sizeof(Node) = " << sizeof(Node) << std::endl;
}
```

As pointed out in the comments, your `Node*` members, `lchild` and `rchild` only get stored as *pointers* to type `Node`, they don't store an entire additional `Node` object each, as you suggested.

Note that the actual size of your objects as returned by `sizeof()` will vary from platform to platform and possibly even within the same platform. Observe sample output of the above program, running on 64-bit Linux:

```
sizeof(int) = 4
sizeof(Node*) = 8
sizeof(int) * 3 + sizeof(Node*) * 2 = 28
sizeof(Node) = 32
```

Note that in this case, even our estimate of the size by summing the size of all the members is incorrect
—the compiler does not have to align data as compactly as possible, and it didn't seem to do so in this case, hence why `sizeof(Node)` is larger than our estimate of it.

This is different to the size you get reported in your IDE, but neither is incorrect —the compilers are just choosing to arrange the struct data differently in either case.

Another factor that can affect this is if `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(void*)` varies across platforms, which is not unheard of. `int` is only required to be *at least* 4 bytes wide, but can be wider, and pointer could be 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the data model used by the system. It looks like your pointers are 4 bytes wide...